# SQLite c# : How to save and retrieve custom object in sqlite BLOB datatype?

Tags: c#, sqlite

There is a custom object(ex company) and list of custom object (ex employee) which needs to be saved in a BLOB datatype, Below is the piece of code I have tried without success. I have tried `DbType.Binary` but it did not workout. 

Below is the piece of insert query :

```
sql_cmd.Parameters.Add("@company", DbType.Byte); 
sql_cmd.Parameters["@company"].Value = (Company)root.company;


sql_cmd.Parameters.Add("@employees", DbType.Byte);
sql_cmd.Parameters["@employees"].Value = ((List< Employee >))root.employeeList;
```

Exception :

```
System.FormatException was unhandled by user code.
Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Below is the associated classes

```
 class Company
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<Package> packages { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }

 class Employee
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public object description { get; set; }
        public Address address { get; set; }
        public Contact contact { get; set; }
        public string enterpriseId { get; set; }
        public object createdDate { get; set; }
        public object modifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Sqlite.net-PCL you can store an entire object. But not in blob type.
Also you must have a separate table for 'package' objects. you can add a company id property to the package object so you can find the items easily. Also it has a cleaner syntax.

```
db.CreateTable<Company>();
db.CreateTable<package>();

db.InsertAll(AlistOfCompanies);
```

Comment: I am working on a outlook widget using c# and SQLite, I just went through some Sqlite.net-PCL related pages, looks compact and decent ! can I use it for my application?

Comment: yes of course.. check whether the nuget package is available for your project type.